# Managing multiple versions of the same Android Library Project

Tags: android, libraries, versioning, android-development

I have an Android Library Project which I intensively used in a few projects. I started a new project in which I am also using this library. I want to improve some things in library (method signatures\names, interfaces, etc.). But if I change method signatures\names, interfaces, I should update old projects that use this library. That could be hard work.

I want to make new version of my library which will be not compatible with previous versions.

Is this possible without creating new project?

IDE: Android Studio.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub sounds like a good tool you could use. It can even be [linked to Android Studio to automatically update your work.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644946/how-do-you-sync-projects-to-github-with-android-studio) You'll be able to store multiple versions of this library. Old projects can reference the older library, while new projects can reference the new library.

Alternatively, however, why not simply recreate the library and adjust it for your needs? If the project itself has a different set of demands, surely it requires it's own library not a bent version of a previous library.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need create new project of course. Only Commit/Push project to Git.

Android Studio - GitHub Integration & Sharing Video
**[Watch on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ldmc757EXaE)** and create new branches for every version library You have.

It's very easy.

---

You can also create local subversion repository.

**[How To connect Android Studio to SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679332/connect-android-studio-with-svn)** & **[Subversion client for Windows](http://tortoisesvn.net/)**